# Transforming the first char of every word in a sentence to uppercase

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

***I'm currently studying C, if this question seems an easy one or a newbie ones, then you know why. Also I already searched here on SO before posting this question. It seems that there are a lot of them but they are not about C, instead Java, php and others.***

I'm working on a simple program that has to transform the first char of every word uppercase. For example if the input is :

> hello my name is claudio

the output would be

> Hello My Name Is Claudio

This is what I coded so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

        char sentence[21] = {'\0'}, sentence2[21] = {'\0'}, *token = NULL;

        fgets(sentence,21,stdin);

        token = strtok(sentence," ");

        while(token != NULL)
        {
                *token = toupper(token[0]);
                strcat(sentence2,token);
                token = strtok(NULL," ");
        }

        puts(sentence2);

return 0;

}
```

The output is :

> MyNameIsClaudio

Obviously that's not what I was expecting, as explained above. I thought that I would have been able to solve the problem simply adding a space like that:

```
token[strlen(token)+1] = ' ';
strcat(sentence2,token);
```

But again, the output is not the one expected :

> MyAmeSLaudio

Hence, to achieve the desired result I tried :

```
null_char = strrchr(token,'\0');
*null_char = ' ';
```

But neither this seems to be the right way. 
Currently I'm am on a dead end. Can somebody give me a hint on how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Walk through the `sentence[]` array and for each letter after a space, insure it is uppercase.

Comment: `char sentence[21]` is small to sample input. `frase` typo as `sentence`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fixed code. Thank you for finding out the typo. Is not easy to think in a language, write and read in another and looking for  the mistake :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to concatenate a space after concatenating the converted string:

```
strcat(sentence2,token);
strcat(sentence2," ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative: walk the array

`strtok()` looses the space delimiters.  This approach maintains groups of spaces.

Walk through the `sentence[]` array and for each letter after a space, insure it is uppercase.

```
fgets(sentence1, sizeof sentence1, stdin);

int precious_space = 1;
size_t len = strlen(sentence1);
for (size_t i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  sentence2[i] = previous_space ? toupper((unsigned char) sentence1[i]) : sentence1[i];
  precious_space = sentence1[i] == ' ';
}  
fputs(sentence2, stdout);
```

---

Alternative loop.  See [@l3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935212/transforming-the-first-char-of-every-word-in-a-sentence-to-uppercase/34935420#comment57603577_34935420)

```
size_t i
for (i = 0; sentence1[i]; i++) {
  sentence2[i] = previous_space ? toupper((unsigned char) sentence1[i]) : sentence1[i];
  precious_space = sentence1[i] == ' ';
}  
sentence2[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: `strlen()` isn't needed either: `for (size_t i = 0; sentence1[i]; i++)` would also do.

Comment: What do you mean saying "strtok() looses the space delimiters"? The token I've found aren't null terminated?

Comment: @l3x True - almost.  if code used `sentence1[i]` a null character would need to be append to `sentence2`.  Thought this way would be clearer for OP.

Comment: @Claudio Cortese " token I've found aren't null terminated" -- The `char *` returned by `strtok()` is `NULL` or a pointer to a _string_. By definition, a _string_ always ends with the null character.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this line to put the spaces back in

```
    while(token != NULL)
    {
            *token = toupper(token[0]);
            strcat(sentence2,token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            if (token)
              strcat(sentence2, " ");
    }
```